# Moving object in list

Tags: python

I made a list like this:

```
mapxy = [[0 for x in range(16)] for x in range(16)]
```

and I add object from another normal list like this:

```
for y in range(0, 16):
    for x in range(0, 16):
        mapxy[x][y] = mapList[o]
```

Then I want to move one object in the list both down and just change the first index moving it left and right in the list `mapxy[x+1][y]`

```
mapxy.pop(f_pos_x)
mapxy.insert(f_pos_x + 1, ["1"])
f_pos_x += 1
```

*(this didn't work quite as I wanted it too, it ended up in-between/created another list inside the first list instead of inserting in the inner list like I wanted it to.)*

but also up and down on `y`: `mapxy[x][y+1]`.

How I want it to look:
Original

```
 mapxy = [[" ", " ", "1"," "][" ", " ", " "," "][" ", " ", " "," "][" ", " ", " "," "]]
```

When i press right:

```
mapxy = [[" ", " ", " ","1"][" ", " ", " "," "][" ", " ", " "," "][" ", " ", " "," "]]
```

And when I press down:

```
   mapxy = [[" ", " ", " "," "][" ", " ", " ","1"][" ", " ", " "," "][" ", " ", " "," "]]
```

Comment: maybe it be more clear if you show an example !

Comment: You are explicitly `insert`ing a new, single-element list into `mapxy`. If that's not what you want, why `["1"]` rather than `"1"` (or `1`, an actual integer)?

Comment: Im sorry, my friends stressed me out so it seems I tohught i finnished the question before I did. Its suppose to say that I remove it after aswell to more or less "move" it. Im going to edit it soon.

The reasons to why its ["1"] i dont honestly know... As I said I barely get alot of this and am very new to it, thats why I am asking for someone to help me.

Comment: You could show an example 4x4 array before and after the operation.

Answer (score 0):

`mapxy` is a list of lists (with apparently all "cells" initialized to the single item `mapList[o]`, which is slightly strange).  So `pop` and `insert` into it would remove and respectively add a whole list at a time, not a single item.

You say you want to "move" an item but not what should take its place.  If you just want to **copy** the item, it's clearly just:

```
map[x+1][y] = map[x][y]
```

but if the previous `map[x][y]` must be filled w/something else you'll then have to assign to that, too, of course.  Exactly the same for "moving" along `y` rather than along `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary with a tuple as key:

```
map = {}
for x in range(16):
    for y in range(16):
        map[x, y] = 0
```

Actually, you could avoid the initialization and check whether an element is set or use a default value. Concerning this default value, consider `None`, too. With this dict, you can "move" elements easily:

```
map[1, 2] = 42
v = map.pop((1, 2))
map[3, 4] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full script that I think does what you want. But before I just paste it and run away, there two things worth saying. 1. You need to swap items in-place. 2. You need to cater for the out of range index errors.

To first i envisaged using a `deque` of deques with `maxlen` field set. `deque` is available from the `collections` library. So to shift left, you pop at the right and insert at the left and to shift to the right you pop at the left and append at the right. But then I had another idea.

You stick with the list of lists, you swap items in-place and avoid out of range errors by the new computed index is within the set of non-negative integers modulo length of the list containing the item.

Enough talking. To swap in-place in python, given:

```
x = [8, 21, 100, 9, 5]
```

You do:

```
x[2], x[3] = x[3], x[2]
```

Resulting in:

```
x = [8, 21, 9, 100, 5]
```

The script below keeps track of two indices, `x`  corresponds to the index of the item, the string, being moved left and right and `y` corresponds to the index of the inner list item containing the the item to be moved left and right (the inner list itself is moved up and down). By index i mean position. So `x` points to the string, `y` points to the list.

To move up and down the containing list, you only need to know the index of the list to move, `y`. To move left and right the item (the string), you need to know both the containing list index `y` and the item index `x`.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import deque

def move_dowm(data, y):
    old_y = y
    y = (y + 1) % len(data)
    data[old_y], data[y] = data[y], data[old_y]
    return y

def move_up(data, y):
    old_y = y
    y = (y - 1) % len(data)
    data[old_y], data[y] = data[y], data[old_y]
    return y

def move_right(data, x, y):
    old_x = x
    x = (x + 1) % len(data[y])
    data[y][old_x], data[y][x] = data[y][x], data[y][old_x]
    return x

def move_left(data, x, y):
    old_x = x
    x = (x - 1) % len(data[y])
    data[y][old_x], data[y][x] = data[y][x], data[y][old_x]
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataset = [
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
        ['1', ' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    ]
    x, y = 0, 1

    print dataset
    print '-' * 90

    y = move_up(dataset, y)
    print dataset
    print '-' * 90

    y = move_dowm(dataset, y)
    print dataset
    print '-' * 90

    x = move_left(dataset, x, y)
    print dataset
    print '-' * 90

    x = move_right(dataset, x, y)
    print dataset
    print
```